# How to fix ´Subscript out of bounds` error in a loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am programming a specification curve for my bachelor thesis. In order to build a graph which is showing which combinations of specifications is showing a significant result and which aren't I'm trying to create a loop which leads to R testing all the possible combinations.Even though the loop is quite short, there are some error messages and don't understand how to solve the problem.

First of all I created variables to define the possible specifications:

```
outlier <- c("none", "40", "33,40,63", "33,40,54,63")
ineligble <- c("28", "28,38,45,48,56")
gender <- c("together", "male", "female")
regression <- c("ANOVA")
control <- c("none", "premanipulation_mean", "all hormones", "all")
```

The data.frame "specifications" is defined as follows:

```
specifications <- expand.grid(outlier = outlier, ineligble = ineligble, gender = gender, regression = regression,
                              control = control)
specifications <- data.frame(specifications, p_value = rep(NA, nrow(specifications)), f_value = rep(NA, nrow(specifications)), 
                             partial_eta_square = rep(NA, nrow(specifications)), r = rep(NA, nrow(specifications)))
```

As you can see I builded a data frame out of the possible combinations and added columns for the p value, f value, partial eta square and effect size. In order to fill the extra columns with values I added the needed commands at the end of the loop. 
The Loop looks as follows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(specifications)){
  dat <- ccy
  if (specifications$outlier[i] == "none") {
    dat <- dat
  } else {
    if (specifications$outlier[i] == "40") {
      dat <- dat[-11,]
    } else {
      if (specifications$outlier[i] == "33,40,63") {
        dat <- dat[-c(5,11,31),]
      } else {
        if (specifications$outlier[i] == "33,40,54,63") {
          dat <- dat[-c(5,11,23,31),]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(specifications$ineligble == "28") {
    dat <- ccySC
  } else {
    if(specifications$ineligble == "28,38,45,48,56") {
      dat <- ccy
    }
  }
  if (specifications$gender == "together") {
    dat <- dat
  } else {
    if(specifications$gender == "male"){
      dat <- dat[which(dat$gender == "male"),]
    } else {
      if(specifications$gender == "female") {
        dat <- dat[which(dat$gender == "female"),]
      }
    }
  }
  if (specifications$regression == "ANOVA") {
    if (specifications$control == "none") {
      anova <- aov(T_time2_mean ~ posecondition, data = dat)
    } else {
      if (specifications$control == "premanipulation_mean") {
        anova <- aov(T_time2_mean ~ T_time1_mean + posecondition, data = dat)
      } else {
        if(specifications$control == "all hormones") {
          anova <- aov(T_time2_mean ~ T_time1_mean + posecondition + C_time1_mean + C_time2_mean)
        } else {
          if (specifications$control == "all") {
            anova <- aov(T_time2_mean ~ T_time1_mean + posecondition + C_time1_mean + C_time2_mean + sex)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    specifications$p_value[i] <- drop1(anova, test = "F")$"Pr(>F)"[[3]]
    specifications$f_value[i] <- drop1(anova, test = "F")$"F value"[[3]]
    specifications$partial_eta_square[i] <- etaSquared(anova, type = 2, anova = F)$"eta.sq.part"[[2]]
    specifications$r[i] <- sqrt(specifications$partial_eta_square[i])
    specifications$k[i] <- nrow(specifications)
  }
}
```

So what I want it to do is fill up the four extra columns with the p value, the f value etc. But I am receiving the error message "Subscript out of bounds" for the following line:

```
specifications$p_value[i] <- drop1(anova, test = "F")$"Pr(>F)"[[3]]
```

I know what the error message means but I don't know how to solve it. When testing the same command on a random anova outside of the loop it works.

The data used can be found through the following link and is called ccy-source-data:
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/FMEGS6

Comment: Can you please show how ```specifications``` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[3]]` means you are fetching the info on the third row of the anova table. The anova table of the model without any controls only has two rows.

If you are e.g. interested in the results for the variable `posecondition`, then it is much safer to directly subset the relevant information for this variable via rownames than to assume it always sits in position 3.

Here is an example of how to do for p value and F value:

```
results <- drop1(anova, test = "F")

specifications[i, c("p_value", "F_value")] <- 
  results["posecondition", c("Pr(>F)", "F value")]
```